# Is there a 64-bit WinObj or alternative?

Tags: winpe

Sysinternals [WinObj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/winobj.aspx) is a great tool to observe kernel object, I'm using it to find out `\Device\HarddiskVolume5` corresponds to which harddisk partition.

But because it is a 32-bit EXE, it cannot be run from a 64-bit WinPE environment.

Is there any 64-bit alternative available?

Comment: you can try [adding WoW64 to WinPE](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/167983-how-to-add-wow64-to-simple-win8pe/)

Comment: Have you tried the 32-bit version of WinPE?